# draw every 12th circle in red with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw every 12th circle in red.
Currently I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,24} %
    { %
        \if ??
            \draw[red](\x\textwidth/10,0) circle (1);
        \else
            \draw (\x\textwidth/10,0) circle (0.5);
        \fi
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am not sure how to test if `\x % 12 == 0`. How do I do that in Latex?

Comment: In general, `\ifnum \x=12\relax ...\else ...\fi` will check its value for 12.

Comment: Actually, your circles are only 10, where do you want to draw the others?

Comment: Supposed I am drawing 24 circles, I want to draw the 12th and 24th circle in red.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A different version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand\Ncirc{24} % number of circles
    \draw (0,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
    \foreach [count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as \y using {int(mod(\i,\Ncirc/2))}] \x in {0,...,\Ncirc} %
    { %
        \ifnum\y=0
            \draw[red](\x\textwidth/\Ncirc,0) circle (1);
        \else
            \draw (\x\textwidth/\Ncirc,0) circle (0.5);
        \fi
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to be the TikZ/PGF way and should probably be preferred; it's also (at least for me) a lot easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. But as I tested it, the first node will not be drawn red. But shouldn't the modulo of 0 % 12 to be equal 0?

Comment: @Pascal Counting starts at 1, use `count=\i from 0` to start at 0.

Comment: @Pascal, if I understand you correctly, than you looking for the following variation of the *Torbjørn T.* answer: `\foreach [count=\i,evaluate=\i as \y using {int(mod(\i,12))}] \x in {0,...,24} %
    { 
        \ifnum\y=0
            \draw[red](\x\textwidth/25,0) circle (1)
        \else
            \draw (\x\textwidth/25,0) circle (0.5)
        \fi;
    }`

Answer (score 8):

As I said in my comment, `\ifnum \x=12\relax...\else...\fi` can be used to determine the 12th loop.  But if you need to find multiples of `12`, I here use a separate index `cindex`, that tracks with `\x`, but is reset to `0` whenever it reaches `12`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{cindex}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
    \setcounter{cindex}{0};
    \foreach \x in {0,...,24} %
    {%
        \stepcounter{cindex};
        \ifnum \thecindex=12\relax
            \setcounter{cindex}{0};
            \draw[red](\x\textwidth/30,0) circle (1);
        \else
            \draw (\x\textwidth/30,0) circle (0.5);
        \fi%
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: so I guess there is no command in Latex for the modulo operator?

Comment: @Pascal there may be, but it is not my forte.  Perhaps wait to see if someone provides a better answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Because I was looking at the code from the `chronology` package. An there is the line `\pgfmathsetcounter{stepstart}{\theyearstart+\thestep-mod(\theyearstart,\thestep)}` with this `mod()`. So I thought there would be one.

Comment: `\intcalcMod` from `intcal` might be interesting. `:)`

Comment: And `Mod(x, y)` from TikZ itself.

Comment: @Pascal In comments to my answer, Paulo gives some alternatives.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I solved it with `\pgfmathparse{mod(\x,12) == 0 ? 1 : 0} \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0` which might not be the best solution. I will look into the comments from @PauloCereda

Comment: @Pascal The first circle is numbered 0 by `\x`, therefore, the example has 25 circles and each 12th circle is caught by: `\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x+1, 12))}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0 ...\else ...\fi`.